# is it possible to pass array as obj via nsnotification

Tags: iphone, ios, nsnotifications

I could do this by using protocol and delegate but I would like to try with NSNotification

My task is sending an `NSMutableArray` via notification from one to another view.  Is it possible to do

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"reloadData" object:myArray];
```

Then, in the receiver, how can I get the passed myArray. I was reading and confused about the `userInfo` and `object` of notification object.

Please advice me on this issue.

Comment: yeah I did try but when I catch the passed array.. Should I use `[notification object]` and catch it to NSMutableArray. how about `userInfo`. when should I use userInfo.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

An `NSNotification` has a property called `userInfo` that is an `NSDictionary`.  The `object` is the `NSObject` that is posting the `NSNotification`.  So usually I use `self` for the `object` when I'm setting up the `NSNotification` because `self` is the `NSObject` sending the `NSNotification`.  If you wish to pass an `NSArray` using an `NSNotification` I would do the following:

```
NSArray *myArray = ....;
NSDictionary *theInfo =
  [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:myArray,@"myArray", nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"reloadData"
                                                    object:self
                                                  userInfo:theInfo];
```

And then catch it using the following:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(doTheReload:)
                                             name:@"reloadData"
                                           object:sendingObject];
```

where `sendingObject` is the object that is sending the `NSNotification`.

Finally, decode the array in `doTheReload:` using:

```
NSArray  *theArray = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"myArray"];
```

That always works for me.  Good luck!

Comment: very quick question : when you were saying `where sendingObject is the object that is sending the NSNotification` and what is did is to create `NSDictionary *sentOject = [NSDictionary alloc] init]; and pass it to `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(doTheReload:) name:@"reloadData" sentObject]` and I dont receive a notification at all.... Do I miss something in the middle

Comment: no, `sendingObject` is the object that posted the `NSNotification`.  So if it was posted by your `AppDelegate`, for instance, you would need to put your `AppDelegate` in the `object:` field.  If it was sent by some `viewController` then you would need to put THAT EXACT `viewController` in the `object:` field.  It must be the `id` of the object that sent the `NSNotification`

Comment: just modified and what I did is`[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(doTheReload:) name:@"reloadData" object:[A class]]` ;  I put `[A class]` because A is the object that posted NSNotification.but still not work...I am thinking to create the object of A class by doing A *a = [[A alloc] init] but i doubt this one...

Comment: No, you need to send it with `self`.  You dont pass the CLASS of the object that is sending it, you pass the actual `id` of the object that is sending it, and then you need to catch the actual `id` of the object that it is sent from.  If you don't know how to get that information it may work by using `nil` but I would not recommend it.

Comment: @JustinPaulson if my controller that triggers the notification follows a different 'storyboard path' and does not directly link with the thing catching the notification, is the best way to feed the information through the appdelelgate?

Comment: @ThinkBonobo it really just depends on how you want to do it.  If you can successfully catch the notification, then you might as well use it to pass the userInfo.

Comment: Really Really Thanks @Justin Paulson :)  and sendingObject I pass nil. and it works for me.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `userInfo`.  It is for misc data you want to send with the notification.  The `object` argument is for the object that the event is fired for.  For example, if you want to monitor a certain MPMoviePlayerController (but not others), then you would sign up for only its notifications (via the `object` argument).

Comment: if he posts notification for himself, he could use the both `object` and `userInfo`. just he needs to know what he uses for what. :)

Comment: `userInfo` is a `NSDictionary`.However, I am passing `NSMutableArray`. Like you said, should I create an `NSDictionary` to hold my array.

Comment: I have no idea why this was down-voted. This is exactly the right answer. You store the NSArray inside of the userInfo dictionary. As @borrrden says, the `object` should always be the object that is posting the notification. The array is not posting the notification, so it should not be the `object`. Failure to follow this convention consistently is a source of really frustrating bugs (usually with the symptom of bizarre "does not respond to selector" crashes).

Comment: @ttran Yes, it is a dictionary so that you can conveniently store multiple pieces of information.  Add your array to the dictionary (and anything you would like to)

Comment: @borrrden: I am deciding that should I or should not I create an `dictionary` to hold my `object` such as myArray. Now I know what to do. thanks

Answer (score 1):

it is very consistent because the **object** is the `object` and the **userInfo** is the `userInfo` when you post any notification using the `-postNotificationName:object:userInfo:` method.

yes, you **can** post any subclass of `NSObject` via the `NSNotificationCenter`.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4, Swift 5**

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("favoriteIsDeleted"), object: [message, self.viewModel.deleteSuccessIcon])

@objc func favoriteIsDeleted(notification: Notification) {
    guard let object = notification.object as? [String?], let message = object[0], let deleteSuccessIcon = object[1] else { return }
    // Code here ...
}
```